# abount the singleton beans of spring

Tags: spring

I am reading the 《Spring in Action》, and it says "singleton beans in Spring often don't maintain state because they're usually shared among multiple threads", but in my opinion, a bean in Spring is a POJO, so how can it not maintain state?

Answer (score 3):

> I am reading the 《Spring in Action》, and it says "singleton beans in
>   Spring often don't maintain state because they're usually shared among
>   multiple threads", but in my opinion, a bean in Spring is a POJO, so
>   how can it not maintain state?

Yes, it's better for a Spring/Singleton to not have a state (of course it can uses other Spring/Singletons [also them without a state]) so you can call its methods from different threads without worring about they could messed up its state (it doesn't have one :-)).
Let's think about a calculator that stores its intermediate results inside an internal stack, what can happen if two threads try to calculate something at the same time?

A Spring/Singleton is annotated (and if it's not it's just like it would be) and lives inside the spring context , it's not a POJO.

If you want to have a Spring/Bean with a state you have to use the scope "prototype", with this kind of scope every time you get a bean you will get a difference instance.

Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 2):

The book is implying that the state of a bean may not be trustworthy at a given point in time due to manipulation of its state by another thread.  If multiple threads are accessing the same instance of a bean you cannot be sure of what state changes have occurred on the bean prior to using it.  Since Spring uses `Singletons` by default there is only one instance of a bean.  If multiple threads hit the bean at the same time there could be issues with the state of the bean.

So your correct that the beans will maintain state, however the state may be unreliable due to modifications from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical web application, you have multiple threads (one per request) and all the requests are using the same beans. In a typical layered application, they will uses a *Controller* which uses then a *Service* which uses then a *Repository*. All of these beans should be singletons without any state. Otherwise you will have bugs due to concurrency (e.g. one thread modifies data in a singleton while another thread do the same).

I think that your misunderstanding comes from saying that *bean in Spring are POJO*. Most of Spring beans are stateless beans which I would not describe as POJO.

Answer (score 0):

A Spring bean is considered a POJO in the sense that it does not **need to** adhere to special requirements (implement certain interfaces, extend particular class, be specific in some way, etc.) to be used with Spring.

Depending on the requirements a Spring bean might need to maintain, and operate on, its state.
It also depends on the requirements to consider if the Spring bean should be a singleton or not.
If a singleton Spring bean is maintaining its own state, proper safeguards must be taken to ensure correct concurrent access/modification.

Confusion comes from a general pattern used in enterprise applications where Spring beans are used to implement bulk of the system logic, and support operations.
In these scenarios, generally its a good practice to not have any state in the Spring bean itself, and just be an extension of the Value Object/Data Transfer Object that contain actual state.
Since these Spring beans are not going to maintain their own state, they are almost always created as singletons.

`SomeClass`, `SomeOtherClass` and `Situation` are all POJO in below code.
`SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` are Spring beans but `Situation` is not, which is a DTO.

```
class SomeClass {

    private int x; // not restricted

    public void handleSituation(Situation s) {
        // may or may not use/modify SomeClass state represented by 'x'
        // one approach is to provide all required information through parameters
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass sc;

    public void process() {
        // gets called from another object

        Situation z = new Situation();
        sc.handleSituation(z);

        // other processing
    }
}

<!-- default scope = singleton -->
<bean id="someClassBean" class="SomeClass"/>

<bean id="someOtherClassBean" class="SomeOtherClass">
    <property name="someClass" ref="someClassBean"/>
</bean>
```

This is a slight variation from pure OOP in which above would be coded similar to following.

```
class SomeOtherClass {

    public void process() {
        // gets called from another object

        Situation z = new Situation();
        z.handle();

        // other processing
    }
}
```